# C# app call unsafe function throw dll not found exception, but the dev machine works fine

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, clr

Assume my project structure.

App cs project      ===>  App.dll

XWrapper C++ project  ===>  XWrapper.dll (clr:safe)

x.dll   ===> x.dll(just copy)

In Unsafe.cpp there is a class named XWrapper, which call x.dll using ***LoadLibraryEx***

In app.cs there is a function

```
private unsafe bool callX(){
    XWrapper x = new XWrapper();
    ....
}
```

======================================================================

Machine A has VS2015 installed and build the project. I can debug into the unsafe function successfully.

Meanwhile, when I copy the whole build into Machine B, the unsafe function cannot be executed.

When trying to debug into the function, a **System.IO.FileNotFoundException** exception thrown, saying the **Could not load file or assembly 'XWrapper.DLL' or one of its dependencies.**

Then I check the log through FUSLOGVW.exe, no any errors.

```
LOG: Assembly Name is: XWrapper, Version=1.0.5984.17726, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6a8f2c98accc9ccf
LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns assembly from C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\9AYAC4D8.B5T\ZR9BQ7XN.RBG\4f3d4e8e\80c69e0a_3ab2d101\XWrapper.dll.
LOG: Assembly is loaded in default load context.
```

---

And if I compile this project in Machine B, the clr works on Machine B, and not works on Machine A when moving the build to Machine A.

Note that app are all run in window7 x86 runtime.

It seems clr(unsafe function) only work on a machine that build it, any idea? How should I make a right configuration to fix this?

Comment: Are the two machines of the same architecture?

Comment: @Rob Yes. I use Environment.Is64BitProcess in C# to check this.

Comment: Do you know why your dll is located at this path: `C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\9AYAC4D8.B5T\ZR9BQ7XN.RBG\4f3d4e8e\80c69e0a_3ab2d101\XWrapper.dll`?

Comment: @zespri, I think it is a local cache. The file is identical with the compiled dll in DEBUG or RELEASE folder.